# convert date in format '01st September 2017' to dd.mm.yyyy format in shell

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed, scripting

I have a requirement to convert date in format "1st September 2017" to 01.09.2017 in shell script.
and also this should work for any dates with suffix "st,nd,rd,th". I tried using sed command but no luck.
Please could anyone help!!!!

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please show your coding efforts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ cat file
1st September 2017

$ awk '{printf "%02d.%02d.%04d\n", $1+0, (index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",substr($2,1,3))+2)/3, $3}' file
01.09.2017
```

Given your comment elsewhere in the post about pipe-delimited input (next time include concise, testable sample input and expected output in your question so we're not guessing at your requirements):

```
$ cat file
foo|1st September 2017|bar

$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }
{
    split($2,d," ")
    mth = (index("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec",substr(d[2],1,3))+2)/3
    $2 = sprintf("%02d.%02d.%04d", d[1]+0, mth, d[3])
    print
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
foo|01.09.2017|bar
```

Comment: Works now. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

**sed** + **date** solution:

```
d="1st September 2017"
date -d"$(sed -E 's/^([0-9]+)(st|nd|rd|th)/\1/' <<<$d)" +"%d/%m/%Y"
01/09/2017
```

---

To make it reusable, you can create a function like below:

```
convert_date () { date -d"$(sed -E 's/^([0-9]+)(st|nd|rd|th)/\1/' <<<$1)" +"%d/%m/%Y"; }
```

---

Usage:

```
convert_date "1st September 2017"
01/09/2017

convert_date "25th October 2017"
25/10/2017
```

Comment: Thanks. But how can I make it generic for any dates st/nd/rd/th ?

Comment: Thanks Roman. It works when i pass argument as "1st September 2017", but if value is in pipeline delimited file, it doesn't replace the date. Please help!

Comment: @Nam, work with filenames was not mentioned in your initial question